# Horizontal table becomes vertical

Tags: html, css

A horizontal table (in email) is displayed vertically on mobile, but it should remain horizontal.
I want it permanently horizontal.
Thanks for the help.

[image]

```html
<p><span style="color: #555555; overflow-x: auto;"><strong>Folge uns auch auf:</strong></span></p>
<table class="_ac_social_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="facebook" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
<td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="youtube" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-youtube.png" alt="Youtube" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
<td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="instagram" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="ABC" href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
<td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="wordpress" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="Instagram Armin" href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us3.com/_social_/flat-color-round-instagram.png" alt="Wordpress" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
<td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="website" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="Webseite" href="https://www.wikipedia.com/"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-website.png" alt="Website" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
<td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">
<div class="__ac_social_icons"><a id="email" class="__ac_social_icon_link" title="E-Mail" href="mailto:"><img src="https://herzkanal.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-email.png" alt="Email" width="20" border="0" /></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Email clients are notoriously unreliable. I would just play around with the layout until it worked in the various clients. For example, try getting rid of all those unnecessary divs, as some clients are probably insisting they are block-level elements despite how you style them.

Comment: If getting rid of the divs as suggested by @ralph.m doesn't fix it, try removing the reliance on class and instead put styling in as a style attribute.

Comment: On which mobile email client are you experiencing this issue?